# ¿Como se eliminan imagenes de la carpeta de Resources de Visual Studio 2022, sin que el formulario ya no funcione?

Tags: c#, imagen

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con visual studio 2022 y necesito eliminar unas imagenes que tengo en la carpeta de Resources (imagenes que no estoy utilizando en los formularios) sin embargo, al momento de querer eliminar las imagenes e intentar abrir de nuevo el proyecto, me salta un error ya que no encuentra el proyecto (es necesario volver a meter la imagen en la carpeta para que abra con normalidad de nuevo el proyecto de visual).

[image: Carpeta de recursos]

Comment: Eso puede ocurrir cuando eliminas o mueves archivos de forma externa al editor. Desde el editor, dale clic derecho y elimina el archivo que quieras. O también puedes darle clic derecho y excluirlo del proyecto. Desde entonces no afectará al proyecto si se elimina, renombra o mueve.

Comment: Más allá de lo que mencioné, no queda claro el problema. ¿Cómo estás eliminando el archivo y qué es lo que ves en el editor al abrir el proyecto luego de eliminarlo?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.